# Determine if a Statement/ResultSet are using a Table before a Statement Query?

Tags: java, sql

Here is the scenario I'm working with: I have a [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object that is using a certain Table in my SQL database. The project I'm working in is extremely big and I've traced the SQL [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)s and they are supposed to be closed.

However when I try to execute a [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) on the particular Table in question, I get the following error:

```
SQLException caught in Error Executing SQL statement :Operation 'ALTER TABLE' cannot be performed on object 'CONNECTIONS' because there is an open ResultSet dependent on that object.
```

**Is there any way to determine before i query a Table to check
if a [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)/[Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) object is using the Table in question, in this case the Table "CONNECTIONS", and furthermore get that [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)/[Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) object using the available objects in [java.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) and close it so I can execute my statement?**

Comment: Have you access to the source code of the whole project? In this case, would it be useful to do a massive search looking for String "connections"?

Comment: There is never any hard coded statements for "CONNECTIONS" it could vary. For instance the same problem could occur on another Table called "INPUTS" when trying to ALTER TABLE for it.. if that makes sense? @LittleSanti

Answer (score 0):

You can monitorize each executed Statement interposing your own JDBC driver between the client code and the actual driver. Some work to do, but it is conceptually simple:

1. You must implement your own JDBC driver as a delegated to the actual driver, by implementing `java.sql.Driver`, `java.sql.Connection`, and `java.sql.Statement` (no need to implement ResultSet in this case). Hey, don't shiver: You don't have to code one by one all the JDBC methods; in practice it will be enough to instantiate a **dynamic proxy** for each interface.
2. The dynamic proxy must simply delegate to the target object. And have an special behaviour for the `Statement.executeQuery()` and `Connection.prepareStatement()` and `Connection.prepareCall()` methods: Whenever any of these methods are been invoked, you should get the first parameter (which is a String containing the SQL statement) and parse it looking for the targeted table names (in your example "connections"). Depending on the required accuracy, you should do a complete, strict SQL parsing, or maybe you can get by with a simple substring search through `String.indexOf(...)`.
3. When the parsing is positive, it's up to you: You can spill out to the console the complete current stack trace (so that you can process it afterwards to fix the client classes), or store the source Statement object to an accessible object store (maybe a singleton map), so that you can close it from another point in your code...
4. The last detail is how to replace the actual driver by your own "spy" driver. It is simple: Just make your driver recognize a special type of JDBC URLs (for example `jdbc:my-spy-driver:thin:@localhost:port:etc`), and make the client code use that URL.

Note that using this kind of driver will penalize performance.